# How to record all of a turtle’s activities to a file, in NetLogo?

Tags: record, netlogo, agent, turtle-graphics

I try to figure out if it is possible after running Netlogo model to get a file with all what is done by the individual turtle from start to the end. i.e. records of all actions and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything built in that would provide this capability; it's something you have to program yourself, using NetLogo's file output primitives.

For sample code you can copy and adapt, see File Output Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.